# PHP remove eveything between style="" tags?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I am interesting in removing everything in between and including the inline style tags from my output. for example:

**style="height:10px;"**

The issue I have been having is, I found some php replacement expressions that work, however they are also removing my paragraph tags and such.

Any help with this is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: How are you fetching/outputting the HTML?

Comment: The output is a wordpress post which I am storing in a variable like this: $content = get_the_content();

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$html = preg_replace('%style="[^"]+"%i', '', $html);
```

Comment: That is still stripping out the <p> tags for some reason. Thanks though

Comment: @levi It doesn't have to be, it only strips style attributes from tags, but not tags themselves. Are you sure your markup is proper?

Comment: I am applying the filter to wordpress posts content, before outputting it. Your code is removing the inline style, however all my p tags are gone as well.

Comment: @levi: Probably because `+` is greedy. Replace it with `+?` to fix if so. Although I do not recommend this solution -- regexes are not for parsing HTML. Use `DOMDocument` instead.

Comment: It is still stripping the p tags with that updated code. can you write a quick example of how to apply this with DOMdocument? I am currently storing my content like this: $content = get_the_content() Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 2):

Use DOM Document to remove the attribute of the tags.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: If I understand correctly that would involve using javascript, but I am trying do this with PHP

Answer (score 2):

This should do it using DOM and a simple XPath query to find relevant elements:

```
<?
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$search = new DOMXPath($doc);
$results = $search->evaluate('//*[@style]');
foreach ($results as &$result)
    $result->removeAttribute('style');
$newhtml = $doc->saveHTML();
?>
```